# how to show the same thing of <asp:BoundField> using <asp:TemplateField> in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

previously i used asp:BoundField in the gridview for showing a data in the column..but i want have the same feature like headerText using asp:LinkButton..my two codes are..

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Contest Name" ItemStyle-Width = "250px" DataFormatString="<a href= Dynamic.aspx?filepath={0}&ID=3>{0}</a>" HeaderText="Contest Name" HtmlEncodeFormatString="False" >
                <ItemStyle Width="250px" CssClass="itemstyle"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
```

same thing using asp:TemplateField

```
 <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemStyle Width="250px" CssClass="itemstyle"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton Text='<%Eval("Contest Name") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("Dynamic.aspx?ID=3&filepath={0}",  Eval("Contest Name")   ) %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

the problem i am facing is that while using linkbutton the text is not changing..it is always showing the "<%Eval("Contest Name") %>"..but it will be from my database Contest Name..this portion is doing nice in asp:BoundField..how can i do the same thing in asp:templatefield..i also want to have the headertext..

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer

```
<asp:TemplateField >
            <ItemStyle Width="250px" CssClass="itemstyle"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("Contest Name") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#     String.Format("Dynamic.aspx?ID=3&filepath={0}",  Eval("Contest Name")   ) %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```